# T-SQL, LINQ Не работает запрос при добавлении условия

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Заполняю дата грид следующим запросом:

```
DataReports.ItemsSource = this.db.contractview.Where(p => p.номер_менеджера == this.idmanager && p.Дата > dstat && p.Дата < dend).ToList();
```

Но она ничего не возвращает. Если убрать выборку номер менеджера, то все заработает.

```
select * from dbo.contractview where номер_менеджера = 8   and Дата <= '01-12-2022'  and Дата >= '01-11-2022'
```

тот же запрос на t-sql работает.

Скажите, что подправить, или как переписать запрос.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `this.idmanager` в условии фильтрации написать `8`, чтобы точно соответствовало SQL-запросу, и от этого уже смотрите. Кстати, у вас на SQL нестрогое условие проверки даты, а в LINQ - строгое.

Comment: все работает и с явным указанием, и со ссылкой. Но стоит мне добавить третье ограничение выборки - перестает работать.

Comment: Проверьте, какой SQL запрос формирует ваш EF query любым из способов: https://eamonkeane.dev/3-ways-to-view-sql-generated-by-entity-framework-core-5/

Comment: Чему равны `dstat` и `dend`?  Какой у них тип: строка или дата?  Допустим ли для них формат `dd-MM-yyyy`?  Или эти строки интерпретируются как `MM-dd-yyyy`?

Answer (score 0):

В C# у тебя ">" и "<", а в SQL ">=" и "<="

Попробуй так:

```
DataReports.ItemsSource = this.db.contractview.Where(p => p.номер_менеджера == this.idmanager && p.Дата >= dstat && p.Дата <= dend).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

После десятков переписываний все заработало, ошибка так и не была найдена. Разные варианты пробовал и ">" и "=>". Может проблемы с сервером были.
var a = this.db.contractview.Where(p => p.номер_менеджера == this.idmanager && p.Дата < dend && p.Дата > dstat).ToList();